# C# shared folder access gives Logon failure exception

Tags: c#

I have the following code which is working fine.

```
public Foo GetConfiguration(string file)
{
    lock (_lockObj)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo ();
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Foo));
            using (Stream reader = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                foo = (Foo) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(string.Format("Failed to read foo '{0}'. Error: '{1}'", file, ex));
        }
        return foo;
    }
}
```

}

when the function input `file` value is a unc shared folder i get the following exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

How can i overcome it?

How can i pass credentials to the FileStream?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
1. This program is hosted on a Windows Service under Local System Account

1. The Service is on Win2008
2. On the server, i added the credentiad to Credential Manager (Store Credentials for automatic logon)
3. After putting the credentials in the Credential Manager i am being able to reach via UNC to the target path (which is on a different server) but still not working via C#

Comment: what account does the windows service run as? Where is the file? does the account (the first) have access to the file (the second)?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have and ASP.Net application that does not run under account that has access to the share.

To diagnose - debug the code and see what the values of `System.Environment.UserName` and `System.Environment.UserDomainName` are.